# how to select column from second cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I have written code for generating the graph by clicking the button and it is working correctly.

The problem is it is selecting the entire column i,e starting to end, so I want to select the specified column from second cell.

Here is my code:

```
Dim ch As Chart
Set ch = ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Add
Set ch = ch.Location(Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=assume)

With ch

.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines

With .Parent
    .Top = Columns(b).Offset(0, 4).Top
    .Left = Columns(b).Offset(0, 4).Left
    .Name = "ch"
End With

End With


Dim sh As Series
Set sh = ch.SeriesCollection(1)

 With sh
.Values = Columns(b).Offset(0, 0)
.XValues = Columns(b).Offset(0, -2)
End With
```

Here "assume" is variable that holds the sheet name. and "b" is variable that holds the column name example "a" "b" ...

soo if "b"= coulmn "e" then it should select the data from second cell of  Columns(b).Offset(0, -2)

Comment: you know that "b" has to be a number not a character? and further, could you rephrase your basic problem, I am not sure about it: do you want just a single cell as the xvalue?

Comment: another thing: `Columns(b).Offset(0, -2)` gives you the whole column 1, if b=3 - not the second cell, that would be `Columns(b).Offset(2, 0)` but this won't work, because `Columns` is selecting the whole column, which you cannot offset any further - you have already everything.

Comment: are you trying to select the data range that is that column. So if the data is in Range("B2:B10"), you want to chart that data, where you pass the column letter as a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Columns(b)` with for example `Range(cells(2, b), cells(65536, b))`.

65536 is highest possible row number in Excel 2003, don't know what it is in the later versions. Just put whatever the last row number is in your case.